# How to open Kibana discover url with filters from the elastic REST API

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, kibana, rest

I am using Elastic REST API to access the `_search` and `_count` api endpoints, for our own app to yield the logs and handle some app specific business functions (based on the logs and determine the performance etc.). From our app, we would like to open the Kibana Url for the search items we yielded from the REST API with the same filters, parameters etc.

By most of the usage, we use the `Application.Name` filter, `date range` with the Search keyword.

Is there a way to create or form the url based on these parameters, that would open up the Kibana discover url with the matching results? (via the api or some other manual ways is also fine, but to how to generate the url like

`/app/kibana#/discover?_g=h@2294574&_a=h@1495984`

which is nothing but i have added a filter by Application.Name, date range for last 30 mins or something like that. I would like to generate the above url by code or may be, if the REST API allows to generate for the search requests and response we get via the REST API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible with some URL reverse engineering.
I suggest you to set your filter on the discover page, then copy and tweak the url :
[image]

Then the URL looks like this:

```
/app/kibana#/discover?_g=(filters:!(),refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:0),time:(from:now-15m,to:now))&_a=(columns:!(_source),filters:!(('$state':(store:appState),meta:(alias:!n,disabled:!f,index:ff959d40-b880-11e8-a6d9-e546fe2bba5f,key:category.keyword,negate:!f,params:(query:'Men!'s%20Clothing'),type:phrase),query:(match_phrase:(category.keyword:'Men!'s%20Clothing')))),index:ff959d40-b880-11e8-a6d9-e546fe2bba5f,interval:auto,query:(language:kuery,query:''),sort:!())
```

You can find and replace the terms you need to change easily in your app (see the *Men!'s%20Clothing* in my URL).

Comment: Before i could agree to this as the answer, I am still curious as to, isnt there any API end point or option from Elasic APIs to generate such? I just wish - Dont you think its a good feature on their end to produce/yield one such? :)

Comment: well, i found a way of going around this, by reversing the filters and options. will update and post my approach once i find it works as expected. Working on it..